# How to resolve (get) the IP of a public domain name for esp8266 by specifying a particular DNS

Tags: dns, esp8266, arduino-ide

I want to know the IP of a public domain name like stackoverflow.com e.g. using my esp8266. 
I know there is a method `WiFi.hostByName("www.stackoverflow.com",IP);`
But this does not allow me to specify a particular specified DNS like 8.8.8.8
And I don't want to connect my esp8266 by specifying a primary and secondary DNS, instead it will get these info automatically from the router.
I want this procedure to overcome an issue with my esp8266. So I need to get the IP from a specified DNS server.

I have seen this interesting [library](https://links2004.github.io/Arduino/d3/d7c/class_d_n_s_client.html#a0f66ce3af99bd8c01b965f3945597c9a) but it uses EthernetUDP which I shouldn't be dealing with.

I tried the following :

```
#include <Dns.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  WiFi.begin("SSID", "password");
  DNSClient dnClient;
  IPAddress IPtofind;
  const IPAddress DNS_IP( 8, 8, 8, 8 );
  dnClient.begin( DNS_IP );

  if(dnClient.getHostByName("stackoverflow.com", IPtofind) == 1) {
    Serial.println(IPtofind);
  }
  else Serial.print(F("dns lookup failed"));
}
```

but the compiler complains about

```
static void EthernetClass::begin(uint8_t*, IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress)
```

and it has the right for that.
Do you have any simple solution ?
It really should be simple I feel !

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with getting a working code to resolve DNS onto IP. Some working code in C++ somewhere. Since the mentioned library in the question is specific to a particular chip as it seems.

Comment: Dns.h is in Ethernet library. remove it from your sketch

Comment: use WiFi.config https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#config

Comment: @Jurai WiFi.config fixes a static IP to the module, and that is not the case.

Comment: Also, the idea was to use DNSClient, so can't remove Dns.h unless I have a better way to resolve the domain name onto IP.

Comment: Again, I guess I must send a raw query and analyze a raw response. I hope I find a good one.

Comment: the esp8266 doesn't have Dns.h so the include is resolved to the Ethernet library Dns.h

Comment: you could set the special DNS server as second DNS server with SDK function `espconn_dns_setserver` and then use hostByName

Comment: Can espconn_dns_setserver work even with DHCP server allocating dynamically the IP of the esp8266 ?

Comment: I don't know. try it

Comment: ```#include "espconn.h"
IPAddress DNS_IP( 8, 8, 8, 8 );
//then down in setup()
espconn_dns_setserver(0, DNS_IP);//to set the primary DNS to 8.8.8.8
WiFi.dnsIP(0).printTo(Serial); //to read the primary DNS
```
yes I can set the primary DNS even when the esp8266 is connected as a station and gets a dynamic IP address.
Now I will be trying to use this idea, in combination with 
```WiFi.hostByName("www.stackoverflow.com",IPtofind);```
 to check if this overcomes the "issue" I faced.

Comment: Ok, that really solved my issue. So setting (for my issue, actually it is resetting to a different DNS, like 8.8.4.4) the primary DNS did the trick, and it worked even with DHCP ! Thank you Jurai.

Answer (score 0):

The esp8266 core for Arduino doesn't have setDNS like the WiFi libraries from Arduino, even if it should have the same API.

To set the DNS server without static IP configuration to change the DNS obtained by DHCP, you could use the `espconn_dns_setserver` function of the underlying SDK.

Comment: I hope someone in the future does make a method (for esp8266) with a particular argument to choose the DNS IP. That would be a better solution if we don't want to change the primary (or secondary maybe) DNS of the esp8266.

Comment: @YoussefDir, you can do it. add the two setDNS methods as in WiFi and WiFiNINA Arduino libraries and create a pull request in the esp8266 arduino GitHub repository

Comment: Thank you for that note. I will try it by God's will.

Comment: The original post clearly states "I don't want to connect my esp8266 by specifying a primary and secondary DNS, instead it will get these info automatically from the router". In order to use espconn_dns_setserver, you have to disable DHCP.

Comment: @S.Imp, does it matter that you disable DHCP after the IP from DHCP was already retrieved?

Comment: @Juraj it certainly could make a difference if you plan to stay connected for a long time. Your IP address that is allocated might need to change depending on network conditions. It's bad manners to try and use a static IP address on a DHCP network that you don't control.

Comment: @S.Imp, yes, bot that was not the topic of the question and answer

Comment: @Juraj you have evidently misunderstood the original post, and should read it again. The OP asks how to run a DNS query, not how to change the DNS servers used by its wifi connection.

Comment: @S.Imp, OP changed the question. but it is still a question about setting the DNS servers